# Notification below separation line doesn't show small icon on status bar

Tags: android, notifications

Well my question is, that my app starts a service which shows an ongoing notification, for some reason i want it to be below the separation line, but when i make it appear below the separation line, the small icon doesn't show up on the status bar

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_large));
    mBuilder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Testing");
    mBuilder.setContentText(sharedPreferences.getString("notifyText", "Default string"));
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(sharedPreferences.getString("notifyText", "Default string")));
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
    mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not with your code the icon you are using is not proper size.
[See the guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) for small icons. If you are using material design then see  [this guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-app-shortcut-icons) for icons.

Comment: Well i tried that and what i came up with was keeping notification priority as PRIORITY_MIN will show notification below the separation line and not the small icon, giving any other priority shows up the small icon but notification is not shown below the separation line, i'm stuck!

Comment: Remove this line mBuilder.setLargeIcon() and it works perfectly.